# Pattern matching in an array or collection

Tags: c#, array

If I had an array of integers like

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| 1| 0| 1| 2| 0| 1| 0| 1| 0|-1| 0| 2| 0|-2| 0|  > VALUES
+--------------------------------------------+
| 0| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|10|11|12|13|14|  > INDEX
+--------------------------------------------+
```

I am looking for 0 which occurs 7 times in the array above.

But I need to find indexes of 0s in the array like so:

1. I can find 0's that occur only after a slot with a Abs(value) > 1
   (rising of falling)
2. I can find 0's that occur only after a slot with a value > 1
   (rising)
3. I can find 0's that occur only after slot with a negative Abs(value)

   > 1 (falling)

So, looking at array above my logic should show indexes

- 1, 4, 12, 14 - 1st and REST (rising or falling)
- 1, 4, 12     - 1st and RISING
- 1, 14        - 1st and FALLING

The indexes above are valid since the previous value was (Abs(previous) > 1). On the other hand, 0's at index 6, 8, and 10 are of no interest since the previous array value was either 1 or -1 (so Abs(previous) <= 1)

My code below works but I feel there could be a simpler more elegant solution to this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = new int[15] { 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0 };

    bool found1 = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == 0)
        {
            if (found1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i); //print 1st index of 0
                found1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Math.Abs(array[i - 1] - array[i]) > 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("All: " + i);  // print every other that fits
                    //1, 4, 12, 14
                }
            }
        }
    }

    found1 = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == 0)
        {
            if (found1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i); //print 1st index of 0
                found1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Math.Abs(array[i - 1] - array[i]) > 1
                    && (array[i - 1] - array[i]) > 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Up: " + i);  // print rising
                                                    //1, 4, 12
                }
            }
        }
    }

    found1 = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == 0)
        {
            if (found1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i); //print 1st index of 0
                found1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Math.Abs(array[i - 1] - array[i]) > 1
                    && (array[i - 1] - array[i]) < 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Down: " + i);  // print falling
                                                      //1, 14
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to reduce the amount of code, or improve performance?  For example, you could use `int firstIndex = Array.IndexOf(array, 0);` to give the first index of `0`. And you could reduce this down to just one loop (storing the results in 3 separate `List<int>` variables based on if/else conditions)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you.  I am not concerned here with array or loops.  The array data is really coming from an event listener having new and previous value passed into handler.  I am just wondering if there is a more elegant way to detect the change based on these 2 values passed into handler.

Comment: Not sure what you are concerned with then, and I do not know how you intend to use the results, but I might re-write that code as per [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/stephenmuecke/e5d710cdb674ba09af5fc0810e9ae4ed)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  Much appreciated Stephen.  Can you post answer so I can accept it.  Thanks again

Comment: Sure, but I'm still not sure how you wanted to use the results or what you mean by _detect the change based on these 2 values_ (what **2 values** are you referring to) and if that would change the code

Comment: What you see above as array[i-1] and array[i] are actually arguments passed into my event handler as part of custom arguments.  That is what I meant with 2 values.  So, I receive message and my handler, based on the args reads these 2 values and determines if target value should be considered.  The target value is one of the 2 values.

Comment: Slot 1 does not satisfy those conditions.  You can never have negative abs(val).   You fail to test the first zero.   Code does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are unnecessarily looping through the array 3 times (only one loop is required). Its not clear how you will be using the results, but assuming you need to store them, then the code can be simplified to

```
int[] array = new int[15] { 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0 };
// Define 3 lists from the results
List<int> all = new List<int>();
List<int> up = new List<int>();
List<int> down = new List<int>();
// Get the index of the first zero value and add to the lists
int first = Array.IndexOf(array, 0);
all.Add(first);
up.Add(first);
down.Add(first);
// Loop the remaining items in the array and add to the appropriate lists
for (int i = first + 1; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    int current = array[i];
    int previous = array[i - 1];
    if (current != 0)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (Math.Abs(previous - current) > 1)
    {
        all.Add(i);
        if (previous - current > 1)
        {
            up.Add(i);
        }
        else if (previous - current < 1)
        {
            down.Add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is

`all` contains `[1, 4, 12, 14]`, `up` contains `[1, 4, 12]` and `down` contains `[1, 14]`

Answer (score 1):

A lot of extra code in my opinion
You don't need 3 loops
You don't test the first
If the value is zero there is not purpose to subtracting it

```
public static void Zero()
{
    int[] array = new int[15] { 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0 };
    List<int> all = new List<int>();
    List<int> up = new List<int>();
    List<int> down = new List<int>();
    int previous = array[0];
    int current;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        current = array[i];
        if (current == 0)
        {
            if (previous < -1)
            {
                all.Add(i);
                down.Add(i);
            }
            else if (previous > 1)
            {
                all.Add(i);
                up.Add(i);
            }
        }
        previous = current;
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("done");
}
```